# How can I find the local minimum values and of a list in Mathematica?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, minimum

I have interference images, and I have to calculate the visibility. For this I have to find the minimum and the maximum values of the intensity "oscillations".

I've already found the maximums with the FindPeaks function, but I don't know how to find the minimums.
[image]

```
img = Import["/home/martin/Dokumentumok/Egyetem/4. félév/Modern fizika labor/15. Kvantumradí­r/Képek/1a.JPG"];
dat = ParallelSum[ImageData[img, "Byte"][[n]], {n, 3456}];
peaks = N[FindPeaks[dat, 1.2, 1.2, 90000]];
Show[{ListLinePlot[dat, AxesLabel -> {"Pixel", "Intenzitas"},ImageSize -> Full, PlotTheme -> "Classic"], ListPlot[Tooltip[peaks], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.006], Red}]}]
```

If I hover over the red dots, it shows the intensity value, and the position. It would be very good, if I could do the same thing with the minimum values, but unfortunately I can't find a function like FindPeaks.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An old trick used to find the minimum is to find the max of -1 times the data.

```
data = {1, 3, 1, 3};FindPeaks[data]
```

which gives

```
{{2, 3}, {4, 3}}
```

To get the minimum use negate the data

```
FindPeaks[-data]
```

which gives

```
{{1, -1}, {3, -1}}
```

The x position is correct, but the y is negated. So multiply -1 times those y values.

```
Map[({x, y} = #; {x, -y}) &, FindPeaks[-data]]
```

which gives

```
{{1, 1}, {3, 1}}
```

Note: That # and & is a Mathematica shorthand for defining a tiny little function with argument named #. For new users that can be a little confusing, but once understood it is quick to write and simple to use.

Comment: The documentation uses the same trick to find valleys: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-sound-and-signal-processing/valley-detection.html

Comment: Ah, good. Thank you. I didn't find that when I carefully went through the documentation page for FindPeaks. I expected to find it hidden in there somewhere.